# How to exclude rows from table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query, but I need to exclude certain rows. My query:

```
SELECT eo, ac, tc, ac_05
  FROM eng_effect e, eng_tc t, task_c c
 WHERE e.eo = t.eo
   AND t.tc = c.tc
   AND e.ac <> c.ac
```

Which is fine, but I need to exclude combinations of `eo`, `tc` which are in `eng_tc` table.

For example, my query returns this values:

| EO | AC | TC | AC_05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A-CHECK7 | KEB | 1A - 767 | KEA |
| 1A-CHECK7 | KEA | 1A - 767 | KEC |
| 1A-CHECK7 | KEC | 1A - 767 | KEB |

But this rows should not be in the intended result, since in `eng_tc` table corresponding `tc`

for `eo = '1A-CHECK7'` is `'1A - 767'`.

Comment: Could you post some sample data which illustrate what you're saying?

Comment: Please check [`EXISTS` condition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXISTS-Condition.html#GUID-20259A83-C42B-4E0D-8DF4-9A2A66ACA8E7)

Answer (score 1):

I would write the query like this:

```
select
    eo,
    ac,
    tc,
    ac_05
from
    eng_effect e
    inner join task_c c on c.tc = t.tc and c.ac <> e.ac
    left join eng_tc t on t.eo = e.eo and t.tc = e.tc
where
    t.eo is null
;
```

I rewrote your query for readability because you were using rather old-fashioned sql.
I created a left join instead of an inner join for t.
Then I added the `WHERE` clause to filter the result set for any record where there is no corresponding record in t, using one of the key columns - could also have used tc.